# headless chrome runing tests with chrome window

Tags: ruby, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-headless

I'm using capybara, cucumber and poltergeist for automated testing web app
I decided to switch to headless chrome from poltergeist (phantomjs), registered driver in env.rb:

```
Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
   capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
   chromeOptions: { args: ['headless', 'disable-gpu', 'disable-web-security'] })

   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app,
     browser: :chrome,
     desired_capabilities: capabilities
end

config.default_driver = :headless_chrome
config.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
```

Then i registred other driver settings:

```
 Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
   Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, args: 
     ['headless', 'disable-gpu', 'disable-web-security'])
end
```

And when you run the tests, Chrome is loaded, but without the active window. So it should work?
Soon I'm planning to run tests in a docker container (ubuntu without GUI), whether it will be necessary to install Chrome browser?

Mac OS X 10.12.5
Chrome 60
Chromedriver 2.31

Gems:
selenium-webdriver (3.4.4, 2.53.4, 2.53.0)
capybara (2.14.4, 2.10.1, 2.6.2, 2.4.4)
chromedriver-helper (1.0.0)

Comment: Did you find solution for it?